# Using custom font in QTabWidget

Tags: qt, fonts, stylesheet, custom-font

I want to use custom font for my App, so:

- I have installed PT Sans on my Windows 7
- Used that font in stylesheet (I do not work with fonts from code - only in stylesheets)

```
QTabBar::tab{
     min-width: 64px;
     min-height: 21px;
     border-image: url(:images/tab_unselected.png);
     border-top: 3px;
     border-bottom: 5px;
     border-right: 4px;
     border-left: 4px;
     color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family: "PT Sans";
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

- For some reason, the letter spacing is wrong. I tried different font-size in stylesheets but the result is the same. Please see pictures attached.

'I mage' is in focus and has strange gap after "I"

[image]

'Audio' is in focus and there is no gap after "I"

Actually, there are a lot of such places over UI so I don't think this is something specific to QTabWidget only.

I hope someone has already faced such issue and can give me a clue on what the heck is going on here.

Thanks a lot!

UPD. Btw, drawing text via painter somewhere (p->DrawText) works great - no extra spacing occur.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Qt do you use? There was some fix for this kind of issues. Problem appears when font size is not preferred for specific font and text is drawn with half pixels, the rounding problem kicks in and some letters got displaced by one pixel. There are couple bug reports with that for example this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-20900) or [this one](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28774).

Comment: I am using Qt 4.8.4 and VS2010. I've looked through bug reports that you mentioned and indeed I have similar letter spacing issues. But I do not rotate text or use QPainterPath as was mentioned in bug reports. Only UI elements (e.g. QTabWidget, QPushButton, QLabel) display text incorrect. If I draw text manually with QPainter drawText method - it is displayed correctly.

Comment: 1. there are much more this kind of bug reports. 2. You can try Qt5 (they did something with fonts). 3. try experiment with minimum tab width. 4. try different font sizes (usually this problem appears for specific font sizes).